# Receiving Intent while opening an x509 certificate (.crt) from a mail attachment

Tags: android, email, attachment, x509certificate, intentfilter

I want to read/extract data from a .crt file attachment when a user clicks on this attachment in his/her mail client/application on Android. I use the following intent filter in AndroidManifest.xml :

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="content" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-x509-user-cert"
                android:pathPattern=".*\\.crt"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

But his not work.Also, while opening the CRT file from the mail application android prompts to install the certificates. Does this mean that action specified should be something else? What is wrong with this intent filter?

Android version tested with : 4.1.2

Comment: Have you already opened a certificate before and selected that you always want to handle intents that way? If so you can go into settings and reset that.

Comment: Yes, i have opened a certificate before but android did prompt anything to set as default. Also i checked the certificate installer system application in the setting, it has no default launchers/ launching options configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Source code from : https://github.com/netmackan/CertTools/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml

Intent Filter that worked fine for me :

```
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:mimeType="application/x-x509-ca-cert" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Though when i try to find the mime type using the below code snippet :

```
    String mimetype;
    String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(url);
    if (extension != null) {
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        mimetype = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
    }
    Log.d(TAG,mimetype);
```

Output : application/x-x509-user-cert 

The mime type used in the intent filter is different. But, it works. If anyone would comment on this, it would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

You may find [this source code](https://github.com/netmackan/CertTools/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml) useful. The author has two lines for each certificate file extension, with one line commented out to show the difference.

As well, depending on how the email app is posting the intent for the attachment, the scheme might be "file" instead of "content". I'm a bit unclear on that. I'd suggest trying them both. :-)

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <!-- <data android:mimeType="*/*" />-->
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.crt" />
    <data android:host="*" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.crt" />
    <data android:host="*" />
</intent-filter>
```

Comment: The above intent filter didn't work as it is. But, i found another filter on the [source you mentioned](https://github.com/netmackan/CertTools/blob/master/AndroidManifest.xml)
I have answered it below. Thanks you :)

Comment: Which filter? I'll change my answer include it. (Someone else might search and find your question.)

Comment: I just added it as an answer. It works but, there is a discrepancy in the mime type which i do not understand.